# Delegate parameter in interface method

Tags: c#, interface, delegates

I apologise in advance as I feel like I'm going to explain what I want to do really badly.

I have a number of models in my application, each of them implements an interface named "IDatabaseItem", I want each "IDatabaseItem" to have a Delete method which returns true or false, but I also want the method to take in a delegate(string) so when the delete method is performed, I can return a string result too as to whether the operation was successful or not. This will also allow the caller to deal with the result however they so choose. In my application this could be something like a pop-up in the UI.

Here's kind of how I thought I'd implement such a thing.

```
    public interface IDatabaseItem
{
    int Id { get; }
    DateTime Date { get; }

    delegate void DBOperationResult(string result);

    bool Delete(DBOperationResult foo);
}
```

I get a compiler result when attempting the above:
`Error  CS8370  Feature 'default interface implementation' is not available in C# 7.3. Please use language version 8.0 or greater.`

From reading other posts, I think I might be barking up the tree and that Delegates and Interfaces do not mix. But any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should just be able to define the delegate outside of the interface and it should work.

Comment: Delegate needs to be defined outside of the interface. it is still not clear how would you return the value returned by the delegate to the interface method caller.

Comment: This is a very strange API. You want to synchronously report success/failure, but report failure mode using an asynchronous callback? Why can't you use Exceptions like normal people? Alternatively, you could return `DbOperationFailure?`, where a null result means success...

Comment: Fair points. Maybe I need to reconsider using a delegate at all in this scenario. Maybe I should just use exceptions as Aron suggested and be a "normal" person. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration of a delegate is a type itself, like declaring an interface or a class. Interfaces do not support nesting types in C# 7.3 and prior. To get your code working, you have to move the delegate declaration to the outer scope.

```
public delegate void DBOperationResult(string result); // a type itself

public interface IDatabaseItem
{
    int Id { get; }
    DateTime Date { get; }

    bool Delete(DBOperationResult foo);
}
```

With the introduction of 'default interface implementations' in C# 8.0 interfaces have been extended to permit the declaration of nested types (like your delegate).

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods for more details.

Comment: Thank you this is perfect and exactly what I was looking for as an answer. Well described. I understand it a lot more now. Really appreciate it.